# Finding perpendicular and parallel points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to find the points marked in a picture (`P0', P1', P2 ', P3'`)

Points are known:

- `P0, P1, P2, P3`
- `l1` and `l2`

**Point** = `Vector3(x,y,z)`

**EDIT:**

Initially I am trying to set the point `P0'`

```
var l1 = 1.2f;
var l2 = 0.7f;

var v30n = (P3 + P0).normalized;
var v10n = (P1 + P0).normalized;

var pl1 = P0 + v30n * l1;
var pl2 = P0 - v10n * l2;
var P0prim = pl1 + pl2;
```

[image]

Comment: @Sinatr I added a code snippet for point `P0`'. It's just an attempt to find a solution

Comment: The is a trick for making this problem simple by using trig instead of algebra. You have 4 lines 1) P0-P0' 2) P1-P1' 3) P2-P2' 4) P3-P3'.   The angle of these lines is the ARCTAN L1/L2.  You also calculate the two lines 1) P0-P2 2) P1-P3.  The slope of the these two lines is m02 and m13 which is also angles.

Comment: If this represents a rotated box, you could represent the box as a center point, rotation, and size. Then changing the size would be trivial, but you would need to calculate the corner positions on demand. The advantage would be less data to store, and a better guarantee that it is an actual box. If you just have four points they might describe an arbitrary polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful with the directions:

```
var l1 = 1.2f;
var l2 = 0.7f;

var v30n = (P0 - P3).normalized; //corrected here
var v10n = (P0 - P1).normalized; //corrected here

var pl1 =  v30n * l1;
var pl2 = v10n * l2; // corrected here
var P0prim = P0 + pl1 + pl2;
```

Did not debug that out, but the direction is: `(final point - starting point).normlized`

Comment: just at the end you need only add up p0 instead of adding two times
var pl1 =  v30n * l1;
var pl2 = v10n * l2;
var P0prim = P0 + pl1 + pl2;

Comment: should not be var P0prim = P0 + pl1 - pl2; instead of +?

Comment: dont think so. Check [here](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay you're completly right, my fault

Answer (score 2):

What @rustyBucketBay says is the correct answer (he was faster than me!), but **in case you know that the proportions of l1 and l2 are equals**, you can also do the follow:

We know that If you sum all the X's and divide by 4 (the number of corners) and do the same for the Y's, you will have the center of the square.

So if we sum l1+l2 to every point of the square, and do the same, we will have the expected square but displaced. Now we want to relocate the center of the new big square.

To achieve that we only have to calculate the center of the new big square (again, divide by 4 X's and Y's) and calculate the vector between both square centers, the small one and the big one.

With this calculated vector, we can just sum it to the new big square points, and will be relocated.